# IIR Filters H(z)=Y(z)/X(z) Why do we insert the coefficents of the input for Y(z)?

Tags: z-transform, infinite-impulse-response

The System Function of IIR Filters is defined as

$$H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$$

The Output Signal as

$$y(n)=\frac{1}{a_0}\left(\sum^{P}_{i=0}b_ix[n-i]-\sum^{Q}_{j=1}a_jy[n-j]\right)$$

I do not understand how we get from Y(n) to Y(z)

Most literature just states

\begin{align}
\sum b_iz^{-i}X(z)&=\sum{}a_jz^{-j}Y(z)\\
H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}&=\frac{\sum b_iz^{-i}}{\sum{}a_jz^{-j}}
\end{align}
without explaining how $Y(z)$ and $X(z)$ are derived.

I thought that it is the opposite

$$H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{\sum a_jz^{-i}}{\sum{}b_iz^{-j}}$$

Is it because

$$\sum b_iz^{-i}X(z)=\sum{}a_jz^{-j}Y(z)$$
states that $X(z)$ consists of $a_jz^{-j}$,
and $Y(z)$ consists of $b_iz^{-i}$?

Comment: "Most literature just states" please provide a reference. The second equation is certainly not correct. "without explaining how Y(z) and X(z) are derived." $Y(z)$ is the z-transform of the output signal $y[n]$ and $X(z)$ is the z-transform of the input signal $x[n]$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response Also has 1:1 the second equation, now it is correct. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have four z-transforms here

Input $X(z) = \sum x[n]z^{-n}$, output $Y(z) = \sum y[n]z^{-n}$,  numerator $B(z) = \sum b_nz^{-n}$ and denominator $A(z) = \sum a_nz^{-n}$

Per our difference equation we have

$$A(z)\cdot Y(z) = B(z)\cdot X(z)$$ which makes the transfer function

$$H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{B(z)}{A(z)}$$

$Y(z)$ is the Z-transform of the output signal, NOT the Z-transform of the denominator coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question! Stay healthy and have a good weekend :)